# How to rerun Spyder console automatically?

Tags: python, spyder

How do I rerun a script on the Spyder IPython console?

I have tried `system('python abc.py')` but it runs on another console.

Edit: Nvm I found it.

```
import os 
os.getcwd() 
runfile('abc.py')
```

Comment: If you post that as an answer to your own question rather than an edit then you can "close" the question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os 
os.getcwd() 
runfile('abc.py')
```

Thanks, myself.